# if statement in liquid SCSS file (Slate/Shopfiy)

Tags: css, sass, liquid

I have the following statement in my Slate's layout.scss liquid file inside style/globals.

```
{% if template == 'index' %}
h1 {
  color: yellow;
}
{% endif %}
```

However, the property in not working. If I look the complied theme.scss.liquid file inside the dist folder, the code is the same as above.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This does not remotely resemble the syntax for `if` statements in Sass. http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while

Comment: @DerekBrown they're using Slate, which is a Shopify development framework. This is a liquid snippet. OP needs to re-word the question to get better answers.

Comment: @MatteoBoscolo can you elaborate on "not working?" is the next never yellow or always yellow?

Comment: @kawnah It's never yellow, from the chrome developer tool I don't even see the property with overline as I could expect

Comment: @MatteoBoscolo are you piping your assets from the `dist` to the `assets` directory in your theme? That could be potentially the issue...

Comment: @MatteoBoscolo also for whatever page you're trying to target, make sure that isn't what the template is set for in the admin panel.

Comment: @kawnah nope, I'm working in the src folder, not in the dist. It kinda looks like is not getting compiled. Is ok to use liquid sintax in the scss files, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156606/discussion-between-matteo-boscolo-and-kawnah).

Answer (score 0):

As today you cannot use liquid sintax in slate's SCSS files.